# Angularjs two-way binding in index.html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angularjs. I am trying to build a simple system with a login page and it will redirect to another page after successfully logged in.

I am trying to show all the pages in index.html with ng-view (including login page). I try to use ng-if to decide when to show the navigation bar on top of the page.

The value of vm.page will not change after logged in

**index.html**

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_module/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="node_module/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/login-controller.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="LoginController as lg" >
        <div ng-if="lg.page != 'Login'" ng-include="'view/navigation-top.html'"></div>
    </div>

    <div ng-view></div>

</body>
```

**login-controller.js**

```
angular.module('myApp').controller("LoginController", LoginController);

function LoginController($http, $location, $scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.page = "Login";

    vm.login = function(){
        vm.page = "Main";
        $location.path('/')
    }
}
```

It is working when the vm.page is initiate and set to "Login", but the page does not change when i set it to "Main".

Appretiate if anyone can help me, thank you :D

Comment: You may want to look into using the UI-Router. There are a few good tutorials around the web.

Comment: Alex, thank you for your suggestion, i will look at UI-Router after i solved this prob. :D

Comment: Do you change the value of vm.page manually or by button action or something like that?

Comment: I changed the value of vm.page by button action, calling the vm.login

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the *$location.path('/')* call in your Login-Function. This will navigate to /index.html and re-initialize the LoginController. Therefore the vm.page variable is reset to 'Login'.

Remove the location.path() or create a service which reatains the Page/Login-State.

Comment: I've commented off the $location.path("/") but still getting the same result. The LoginController still re-initialize